# Amateur need help on Excel multiple conditions, using arrays, etc

Tags: vba, excel

First question post here in this website. Using EXCEL now and in need of help in making this.

Making it short, I'm an amateur who seems to have a near impossible task on my hand now and been self-studying my way through but still came up short to the ideal results I'm looking for.

Some of the basics I get, but it seems I'm still missing something that it ends up not giving the results I want.

Here's the objective:
There are only two conditions to be met;
Using the first criteria to search, if it is "C", "D", or "E",
and the second criteria, if it is "a" or "b", to further specify.

In the DATA SHEET, the data below those criteria will be sum up and will be consolidated in the SUMMARY SHEET.

I have tried using SUMIF with the multiple criteria it can have, but there seems to be a problem when using the array B2:S2 with the cells being Merged cells. This is what I used to solve:

`"=SUMIFS(Data!B4:S4,Data!B2:S2,Summary!B2,Data!B3:S3,Summary!B3)"`

Looking forward to finally having a solution for this or even getting near in solving this.

[DataSheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPqXL.png)
[SummarySheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUPix.png)

Comment: I don't know the details of your task, but this looks like a Pivot table could help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

On Summary Sheet,
In B4

```
=SUMPRODUCT((OFFSET(Data!$B$2:$S$2,,CHOOSE(IF(MOD(COLUMNS($B3:B3),2)=0,2,1),0,-1))=INDEX($B$2:B$2,MATCH("zzz",$B$2:B$2)))*(Data!$B$3:$S$3=B$3)*(Data!$B4:$S4))
```

And then copy it across and down.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another answer which modifies a single part of your own function:

```
=SUMIFS(Data!$B4:$S4,Data!$B$2:$S$2,OFFSET($B$2,0,QUOTIENT((COLUMN()-2),2)*2),Data!$B$3:$S$3,B3)
```

I've just changed the `criteria1` of your `SUMIFS` function, and freezed other cells properly.

**Note:** This is not an array formula.

Comment: Mahesh: i upvoted yours but realised that the formula above produces an array with 0s in instead of repeated column values e.g. {"C",0,"D",0,"E",0,"C",0,"D",0,"E",0,"C",0,"D",0,"E",0}  so it only sums correctly for the first part of each merged cell lookup.

Comment: @QHarr, I forgot to mention. This is not an array formula.